# MySQL STR_TO_DATE NULL on error

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm currently migrating a table with dates in `VARCHAR` columns to a new table with `DATE` columns. I managed to sanitize the string values in the old table to the format *"YYYY-MM-DD"* but when I try to perform the insert I got an error with the date *"2006-04-31"* because that April only had 30 days (was a typo when it was registered),

My question is: how can I set to NULL the column when the date is invalid without getting an error? My SQL is the following:

```
INSERT INTO newFancyTable (created_at)
SELECT str_to_date(created, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM oldCrappyTable;
```

And the error is the following:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '2006-04-31' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I also tried using the following approach:

```
INSERT INTO newFancyTable (created_at)
SELECT CAST(created AS DATE) FROM oldCrappyTable;
```

With the same error, and trying to update the `oldCrappyTable` would return the same:

```
UPDATE oldCrappyTable SET created = CAST(created AS DATE);
```

Both return:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2006-04-31'
```

**UPDATE 2**

At last, I used multiple `CASE`s to isolate that invalid dates, in sum they were only 5 of them,
Nevertheless, the issue can be reproduced by doing:

```
CREATE TABLE dates_temp (
  test_date DATE DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO dates_temp
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2006-04-31", '%Y-%m-%d');

DROP TABLE dates_temp;
```

Comment: Why don't you write a `CASE` for it or just filter it out?

Comment: That table has 5000+ rows, I can't know for sure how many dates are invalid.. I konw "2006-04-31" is the first one, but no idea how many others are there..

Comment: Is your column defined as not null? `STR_TO_DATE()` would by default produce a value of `NULL` when the string passed to it represents an illegal date.

Comment: The column can be NULL, indeed SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2006-04-31", '%Y-%m-%d'); returns NULL, but when using it in an UPDATE, INSERT statement it fails.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503845/746347).

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround is to turn off strict mode, either for the whole server, for a particular session, or for just a few statements. For example:

```
 set @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode; 
 set sql_mode = ''; 
 -- Run some statements which may result in error
 set sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;
```

Additional Info

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

Comment: Well that depends, When I've had to do it I am just trying to get all the data into the database. I will perform the necessary clean up on the data after.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @EduardoDennis answer use `NULLIF` to filter out zero dates:

```
INSERT INTO newFancyTable (created_at)
SELECT nullif(str_to_date(created, '%Y-%m-%d'), from_days(0)) FROM oldCrappyTable;
```

See my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503845/746347).