# STR_TO_DATE returns null in SELECTbut throws an error in UPDATE

Tags: mysql, timezone, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to convert strings in one column to dates in a second column.  The dates have varying timezones, so the `STR_TO_DATE` function chokes a bit.

```
createdTime : Thu Oct 08 09:28:18 MDT 2009
```

I can successfully run this statement to get a parsed date for MDT dates and `null` for other dates:

```
select createdTime, str_to_date(createdTime, '%a %b %d %T MDT %Y') from myTable
```

If you change the literal `MDT` in the date string to `MST` you can get all the records for MST timezone.  I have run this successfully.

However, when I try and use the same `STR_TO_DATE` function in an `UPDATE`, it chokes:

```
update myTable
set realCreatedDate = str_to_date(createdTime, '%a %b %d %T MDT %Y')

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'Fri Nov 06 08:48:27 MST 2009' for function str_to_date
```

Why does the `STR_TO_DATE` function throw an error in the `UPDATE` statement rather than just returning `null` like it does in the `SELECT`?

EDIT

To clarify the problem, this `SELECT` statement with a string literal from an incorrect timezone returns `null`:

```
select str_to_date('Thu Oct 08 09:28:18 MST 2009', '%a %b %d %T MDT %Y')
```

while this `UPDATE` statement throws an `Error Code: 1411` :

```
update myTable
set realCreatedDate = str_to_date('Thu Oct 08 09:28:18 MST 2009', '%a %b %d %T MDT %Y')
```

I'm trying to figure out why the `STR_TO_DATE` function in the `UPDATE` throws an error even though the same function in the `SELECT` just returns `null`

Comment: Why do you think it's being called on rows that don't meet the `WHERE` condition? The problem is that it can't convert that string back to a date to do the assignment.

Comment: The error message doesn't say it's trying to assign `NULL`.

Comment: You're right, I incorrectly identified the problem.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Your format string has `MDT`, but the string in the `createdTime` column has `MST`.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were doing, so I deleted that comment.

Comment: Yes, the format string only works for dates with `MDT` instead of `MST` but the point is that for dates with `MST` the `SELECT` statement just returns `null` and the `UPDATE` statement throws an error

Comment: When I try it, the update completes, but I get that message in `show warnings`, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: And it sets the column to `NULL`.

Comment: Just saw your last comment after editing the question.   If you run the update on your DB with the string literal, it just has a warning and not an error?  If so, it must be settings on my DB or in Workbench.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL STR\_TO\_DATE NULL on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686836/mysql-str-to-date-null-on-error)