# STR_TO_DATE giving an error instead of null

Tags: mysql, date

I am taking data from a csv file and throwing it all into a tempory table, so everything is in string format.

So even date fields are in string format, so I need to convert date from string to a date. All dates are in this format 28/02/2013

I used STR_TO_DATE for this, but I am having a problem.
Here is a snippet of my code.

```
INSERT INTO `invoice` (`DueDate`)
SELECT 
STR_TO_DATE('','%d/%m/%Y')
FROM `upload_invoice`
```

There are of course more fields than this, but I am concentrating on the field that doesn't work.
Using this command if a date is invalid it should put in a null, but instead of a null being put in, it generates an error instead.

```
#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
```

I understand what the error means. It means it is getting an empty field instead of a properly formatted date, but after reading the documentation it should not be throwing an error, but it should inserting a null.

However if I use the SELECT statement without the INSERT it works.

I could do the following line which actually works to a point

```
IF(`DueDate`!='',STR_TO_DATE(`DueDate`,'%d/%m/%Y'),null) as `DueDate`
```

So STR_TO_DATE doesn't run if the field is empty. Now this works, but it can't check for a date which is not valid eg if a date was ASDFADFAS.

So then I tried

```
IF(TO_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(`DueDate`,'%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL),STR_TO_DATE(`DueDate`,'%d/%m/%Y'),null) as `DueDate`
```

But this still gives the #1411 error on the if statement.

So my question is why isn't STR_TO_DATE not returning NULL on an incorrect date? I should not be getting the #1411 error.

This is not an exact duplicate of the other question. Also there was not a satisfactory answer. I solved this a while and I have added my solution, which is actually a better solution that was given in the other post, so I think because of my better answer this should stay.

Comment: Check [5.1.8 Server SQL Modes :: SQL Mode Changes in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes). Another option is to use [12.4 Control Flow Functions :: NULLIF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif).

Comment: `mysql > set sql_notes = 0;` it prevent mysql to show warings like 1411

Comment: I have no access to the inner workings on the mysql, on our server. So I don't think I can do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL STR\_TO\_DATE NULL on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686836/mysql-str-to-date-null-on-error)

Answer (score 0):

An option you can try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `upload_invoice`, `invoice`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoice` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `DueDate` DATE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload_invoice` (
    ->   `DueDate` VARCHAR(10)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `upload_invoice`
    ->   (`DueDate`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('ASDFADFAS'), (NULL), (''),
    ->   ('28/02/2001'), ('30/02/2001');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `invoice`
    -> SELECT
    ->   NULL,
    ->   IF(`DueDate` REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}' AND
    ->      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    ->        STR_TO_DATE(`DueDate`, '%d/%m/%Y')
    ->     ) > 0,
    ->   STR_TO_DATE(`DueDate`, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    ->   NULL)
    -> FROM `upload_invoice`;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `DueDate`
    -> FROM `invoice`;
+----+------------+
| id | DueDate    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | NULL       |
|  2 | NULL       |
|  3 | NULL       |
|  4 | 2001-02-28 |
|  5 | NULL       |
+----+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pGBiDe1FZYBcK8duTMYXav/0).

Comment: I actually solved this one a long time ago, but forgot I had posted the question. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I posted this question, but I solved this problem a while ago like this

```
IF(`{$date}`!='',STR_TO_DATE(`{$date}`,'%d/%m/%Y'),null) as `{$date}`
```

So because the line is long and confusing I made a function like this

```
protected function strDate($date){
    return "IF(`{$date}`!='',STR_TO_DATE(`{$date}`,'%d/%m/%Y'),null) as `{$date}`";
}

INSERT INTO `invoice` (`DueDate`)
SELECT 
{$this->strDate('DueDate')}
FROM `upload_invoice`
```

I really forgot I posted this question. It seems like an eternity away, but this is how I solved the issue.